# Can we have more than one "Google Code for Conversion Page" on a page?

Tags: javascript, google-api, tracking, google-ads-api

Can we have 2nd Adwords Conversion Tracking to Confirmation Page? For example with different conversion_id and the same curency.

```
<!-- Google Code for New Booking Code Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = conversion_id;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "5G3JCJiOlmsQzcHS0gM";
var google_conversion_value = 1.00;
var google_conversion_currency = "EUR";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservicesenter code here.com/pagead/conversion/conversion_id/?value=1.00&amp;currency_code=EUR&amp;label=5G3JCJiOlmsQzcHS0gM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: If I put directly 2 one after another, my guess is that I can expect problems as all variables are global, but anyway I will appreciate any opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have all the conversions codes you need. Variables maybe are global, but you are overriding them...

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many as you want (as already mentioned) but what are you hoping to track by having a separate one? Google Tag Manager might be your friend, since you can better control the firing of each tag.